# Smooth camera movement in Unity 2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a 2d RPG game in unity and I wanted to add a smooth camera movement like Brackeys did in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MFQhpwc6cKE).

I already tried to use `FixedUpdate()`, `Update()` and `LateUpdate()`, but nothing when I hit play the camera is like lagging behind the player.
The strange thing is that when I turn off the camera script the player moves fluidly.

I even tried `Vector3.SmoothDamp()` and `Vector3.Lerp()` but nothing it's still a bit laggy.

How do i solve it??

My code by far:

```
public class CameraMovement : MonoBehaviour
```

{

```
public Transform target;
public float smoothing;

void FixedUpdate()
{
    if(transform.position != target.position)
    {
        Vector3 targetPosition = new Vector3
        (target.position.x, target.position.y, 
        transform.position.z); 

        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp
        (transform.position, 
        targetPosition, smoothing);
    }
}
```

}

Target is the Player Transform.

Comment: Hello, welcome to stackoverflow. We can't really help you without seeing some code, can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66026251/edit) your question and post what you have tried?

Comment: The video shows and explains how the script is done and there is a direct link to the script itself. Have you tried following the video? What is your problem? Show the code and the specific problem you are having in the question. You can mention the part of the code the that gives you problems or the part of the video you are having problems with

Comment: FixedUpdate is a bad idea for this, as it only updates every 0.02 seconds (50fps) better do it in LateUpdate and multiply smoothing with Time.deltaTime

Answer (score 1):

Try Removing this -
if(transform.position != target.position)
Statement.

And also multiply smoothing with time.deltatime.
Here-

```
public Transform target;
public float smoothing;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
    Vector3 targetPosition = new Vector3
    (target.position.x, target.position.y, 
    transform.position.z); 

    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp
    (transform.position, 
    targetPosition, smoothing*Time.deltatime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! I tried  and it's still a little bit laggy but it's better then before.
I don't know what is the problem but it's the script bc if i turn off the code in the inspector and add the camera as a child of the player it doesn't lag.
Thanks anyway

Comment: @paracetamolo  try using the script I sent in LateUpdate() instead of FixedUpdate() and put it on Camera Gameobject.

Comment: I did and now it's kinda better.

Thanks anyway.